# Leave One Out Cross Validation - Average weights or error?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

Basically, I have a dataset of 25 points and I ran a split to get 25 unique splits. From the training data I fit a linear regression model. So my question is do I do this for all splits and compute an average of all weights and then compute an error or do I compute the error between every split and average this error?

Im inclined to think it is the latter as the first option presents an issue when computing the error as by computing an average weight, there is no longer a unique test point to compare to.

Comment: You want to average the errors

Comment: Thank you . Just to confirm, I compute the error between each split?

Comment: You fit 25 models. Each of them is fitted on 24 samples and the error for each of them is computed on that one sample that was not included in the training set. So you end up with 25 error measurements and you take the average of these 25 error values.

Comment: when averaging remember that independent errors propagate as variance (i.e squared error), so take the average of the squared errors then apply a square root.

Comment: @MatusDubrava that is only true if for "average" you take the appropriate aggregation procedure for the particular error in question (which is not specified here). E.g. for MSE or MAE, averaging is fine, for RMSE, you need the square root of the average of the squared errors (per fold = here per case).

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX I am using the MSE and so did not take square roots here